# MSBuild how to pass parameters to be used in CPP source file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to use MSBuild parameters inside a source file something like this

msbuild /m /target:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:version_label=2019.12 rlabel.sln

and i want to access the value of "version_label" inside my cpp source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this way is not supported or it can't work well as what you expected I think.

You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties), there're different scopes for different properties like `Reserved properties`,`Environment property` and so on. When we use msbuild to build a C++ project, it will read the content from `.vcxproj` file and execute the [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019) from the [targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) to complete the build.

And to access the value in your cpp source code( in other word, to access the value programmatically), there's no easy msbuild api for this behavior. It means we have to write `hard code` to read the value of `version_label` property in `.vcxproj` file(xml format).

And the reason I think it's not supported or not working exactly is that when we pass the value in command-line, it will only affect the actions in `build time` but not `runtime` of the `output library or .exe`.

**Assuming in this scenario:**

I have a C++ project and I defined a property `version_label` whose default value is `2019.1` in the `.vcxproj` file. And I have written code in my xx.cpp to access the value of the `version_label` by reading content from .vcxproj file.(hard-code way)

Now if I use command: `msbuild /m /target:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:version_label=2019.12 rlabel.sln`, the value `2019.12` will **temporarily** override the `default 2019.1` during build process.(Temporarily: It will not actually change the content in .vcxproj)

So when I call the C++ method in runtime to access `version_label` property, the value will always be `default 2019.1` instead of `2019.12 from command-line`. The value you pass by command-line can only affect build time instead of runtime, so what you want is not supported by this approach.

You can access the `version_label` defined in `.vcxproj` in your source file, but it's hard to access `the value you pass by command-line during build time`  in runtime of the application.

In addition: Maybe there's some workarounds to achieve the behavior you want. We can write the `version_label`'s value into a text file or what during build time. And then in our code, we will read the value from the text file instead of project file(.vcxproj),this can work however, bad idea I think so i didn't want to suggest it.

Asuming you're trying to make something like version-control, I recommend using git. Anyway, to access the *value from command-line*(build time) in C++ code(runtime), not recommended. Hope all above makes some help and feel free to correct me if I misunderstand anything :)

**More details:**

1.For C++ projects, msbuild actually call the cl.exe([Microsoft C++ compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=vs-2019)) to compile the code.

2.So to achieve what you want, the core is to let `cl.exe` access your `version_label` property

3.When using command like: `msbuild /m /target:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:version_label=2019.12 rlabel.sln`, the msbuild can access the property `version_label` obviously during build time, however during compile time(In Clcompile target), the cl.exe(C++ compiler) can't access the `version_label` property. And it's by design which means you can't modify this process. (**Msbuild won't pass the version_label parameter to cl.exe**), see:

[image]

That's why I say it can't work as you expected. Since the compiler cl.exe can't access the custom property `version_label`.

Comment: I understand that its difficult to get the value during runtime of the program. But during the runtime of msbuild itself why the value from project file is not available on source file. Meaning I am not expecting the value to be available during the runtime of my application, but rather I am expecting that this value is available during the compile time of my application. Thats basically the MSBuild having a capability to check for the property mentioned in its command line in the source code. This makes it hard for automation of compile using msbuild and packaging

Comment: @PrasadNair Maybe you can create a target into .vcxproj, this target will [execute after build target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2019#beforetargets-and-aftertargets), use a [SetEnv task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/setenv-task?view=vs-2019) in this target to receive the `version_label` property and set its value in the machine, and use code to access the environment variable. But i'm not sure why you want to access msbuild property in source file, what to do after you access the value?

Comment: Say my intention is automation of the build itself. So say if i pass a custom parameter in MSBuild , I want to check the value of that parameter in the source code and modify that parameter based on some logic. Want to be  specific about this , want to pass the parameter from MSBuild command line , not to read from a file during source code execution.

Comment: Sorry but as far as i know, what you want is not supported for msbuild. MSbuild is only a build engine, it's something used to compile your code, your source code can't access msbuild parameter during build process, also can't access it at runtime.

Comment: Here it doesn't involve runtime access or determination of a variables value. Its all compile time only. Compile time the value specified as a ms build parameter should be used while compiling the code. It doesn't involve run time determination of that value. Thats not working.

For example 
msbuild /m /target:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:version_label=2019.12 rlabel.sln

Here version_label is accessed in the code during compile time not runtime. I just want to print different values based on compile time value of that setting

Comment: @PrasadNair See my `more-details`, hope my description can help you solve the puzzle though the answer seems to be negative. And if it's helpful, please consider marking it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

An option can be defined as a preprocessor definition (C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions) like:

```
version_label="$(version_label)"
```

That define a preprocessor definition with the value.